# Derivative of $\frac{d \int p(x) dx}{d p(x)} $

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

<strike>Suppose $p(x)$ is a probability between 0 and 1</strike> . It looks

$$\frac{d \int p(x) dx}{d p(x)} = 1$$

but I find it a bit difficult to convince myself why? I feel influenced by the fact that $\frac{d \int p(x) dx}{dx} = p(x)$. Can anyone provide a better understanding of the above derivative?

In contrast, I find it relatively more intuitive in the case of a discrete random variable, where

$$\frac{d \sum_{i} p(x_i) }{d p(x_i)} = 1$$

Comment: In fact $ d \int p(x) dx \over {dx}$ is zero since there is no dependence on $x$

Comment: doesn't $p(x)$ depend on $x$?

Comment: yes, but $\int p(x)dx$ does not

Comment: What does this even mean?

Comment: @user619894, for "∫()  does not", is it because it integrates to 1? I removed the constraint that $p(x)$ is a probability, because otherwise its derivative wrt. $p(x)$ would also be 0.

Comment: no, it is because x is the integration variable. the integral depends on the limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{gather*}
Let\ \int p( x) dx=P( x) +C\\
Now,\\
\frac{d\left(\int p( x) dx\right)}{d( p( x))} =\frac{dP( x)}{dx} \cdotp \frac{dx}{d( p( x))}, \\using\ the\ chain\ rule\ of\ derivatives.
\end{gather*}
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I have down voted you because $\int p(x) dx$ is not a function of $x$. $x$ is the dummy variable in the integration, hence $P(x)$ is not a function of $x$, but of the integration limits. The expression $\frac{d (\int p(x) dx)}{d p(x)} $ is an abuse of notation, since this is a functional derivative  and should be denoted as $\frac{\delta (\int p(x) dx)}{\delta p(y)} $ note that the derivative is at position $y$.

Comment: This is not definite integration, but indefinite.

Comment: Exactly. So how is it a function of $x$?